# c program, increment through strings

Tags: c, string, increment, c-strings

I found this program to run through strings and print them.  I know there's an error, but I'm not 100% sure what it is.

```
char *stringOptions[] = {"one", "two", "three"};

void incrementString(char *input) 
{
    static int i = 0;
    input = stringOptions[i % 3];
    i = (i + 1) % 3;
}

void print_string(void) 
{
    char *string = "initial";
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
    {
        incrementString(string);
        printf("%s ", string);
    }
}
```

It is supposed to print out: one two three

Sorry I don't know more about it, it's based on something I was trying to do, but I was unsuccessful reading through the strings.  It is essential that this be in separate functions like this.  Thanks,

Comment: Proper indentation will make everyone a lot happier with your question.

Comment: When you ask a question you should specify both the intended behavior as well as what you are currently seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input = stringOptions[i % 3];
```

this doesn't do anything.  Remember, C passes everything by value, so all you're doing is setting the local copy of input to a new address.  You probably want to pass a double pointer into the function and then set the dereferenced version:

```
void incrementString(char **input) {

...

*input = stringOptions[i%3];
```

then call it like:

```
incrementString(&string);
```

And also what zoidberg said about your loop.

```
for(i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
```

because the second part of a for loop is the condition on which it should continue to loop.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know.  The double pointer fixes everything.  I can vote this as the correct answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: Cool.  Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i = 0; i > 3; ++i) {
    incrementString(string);
    printf("%s ", string);
}
```

That loop will never execute. Change `>` to `<`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistype.  Thanks